# Correct way to connect and test firebase emulator with react native app

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-tools

I am implementing a react native app with firebase as serverless backend. I am facing some errors when trying to connect my app to firebase emulator. I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase package as my firebase module in react-native. Here are a few methods that I tried :

Snippet 1:

```
const firebase = require('firebase/app');
const db = firebase.firestore();

db.settings({ host: 'localhost:8080', ssl: false });
```

Error ::

> @firebase/firestore:, Firestore (7.8.1): Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Connection failed 1 times. Most recent error: FirebaseError: [code=unavailable]: The operation could not be completed

Snippet 2:

```
firebase.firestore().useEmulator("localhost", 8080);
```

Error ::

> TypeError: firebase.firestore().useEmulator is not a function. (In 'firebase.firestore().useEmulator("localhost", 8080)', 'firebase.firestore().useEmulator' is undefined)

Answer (score 0):

You should read the [quickstart](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_firestore), it provides some snippets that you might find useful. Specifically, it looks like it should be `firestore.useEmulator("10.0.2.2", 8080);` without the parenthesis on firestore.

Comment: without the parenthesis? it's a function with required attributes, how would it work without parenthesis? or am I misunderstaning something...?